# Label is resizing incorrectly tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label

This is my first post so be easy on me :)
I have a simple python 2.7 script that creates a window using `overrideredirect(1)`. That all works well and good, the canvas I add works, but when I add a label and apply its height and width, it is severely elongated on both axes.
this occurs for both the title bar and quits labels. I want to get them thinner, but I can't use floats. Any ideas what is happening?
Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from math import *

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        # Create a basic tkinter window
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=700, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()
        # Start function that creates labels
        self.initiate()
        # Make the window frameless
        self.root.overrideredirect(1)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def initiate(self):
        # Create a single black bar across the top of the window
        # My issue is here. I apply the height of 1, and it displays in the tkinter window of a height more like 10-20.
        # I think it has somthing to do with overrideredirect, but i dont know what it is, i have never used it before.
        self.titlebar = Label(self.canvas, width=700, height=1,
            bg='black')
        self.titlebar.place(x=0, y=0)
        # This and the other functions make the window move when you drag the titlebar. It is a replacement for the normal title bar i removed with overrideredirect.
        self.titlebar.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
        self.titlebar.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
        self.titlebar.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)

        # Create a quit button in top left corner of window
        self.quit = Label(self.canvas, width=1, height=1, bg='grey')
        self.quit.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.quit.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.root.destroy())

    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        deltax = event.x - self.x
        deltay = event.y - self.y
        x = self.root.winfo_x() + deltax
        y = self.root.winfo_y() + deltay
        self.root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))


Main()
```

Comment: Please be **much** more specific about what the problem is and indicate the lines of code involved.

Comment: Updated my description. I don't know how else I can explain this, but I added comments. Hope it helps :|

Comment: That a big improvement, however, when I run your code it seems to work OK—or I'm not understanding what you mean by "it is severely elongated on both axes" (assuming by **it** you mean the window) .

Answer (score 1):

Unless your label has an image, the width and height represents a number of average sized characters based on the font used by the Label. A width of 700 and a height of 1 will likely result in something 6000-7000 pixels wide, and 15-20 pixels tall.

If you're trying to create a border, I recommend using a frame since its width and height parameters are in pixels.